# "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string" in my mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

this code works true, but can't get result on mysql table.

```
$interval = $posts[4];
$datestring = $dif;    
list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $interval); 

$date = new DateTime($dif);    
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$hours.'H'.$minutes.'M'.$seconds.'S'));
echo $date->format('H:i:s');
$posts[7]=$date;
```

[image]

Comment: Pay attention to the error message. Not sure where the error is coming at, since it's not in your code here, but you can't use a `DateTime` object as a string. If you're trying to insert it into a database, then use the `format` function as you're doing in your echo.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? and where is the part of your code raises this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign formated value. instead of `$date`

```
 $date = new DateTime($dif);    
 $date->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$hours.'H'.$minutes.'M'.$seconds.'S'));
 $date_format = $date->format('H:i:s');
 $posts[7]=$date_format;
```